# How redirect to any specific page after registration and login instead of default Dashboard

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to redirect user to homepage after successful registration or successful login. I found one module in github, but thisn't working.

Github module link https://github.com/mazestricks/Magento2-CreateAcountRedirect

Answer (score 0):

> **Create a event file: events.xml**
>
> **File: app/code/[Vendor]/[modulename]/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="customer_register_success">
    <observer name="customer_register_success_redirect" instance="[Vendor]\[modulename]\Observer\CustomerRegister" />
</event>
<event name="customer_login">
    <observer name="customer_login_redirect" instance="[Vendor]\[modulename]\Observer\CustomerLogin" />
</event>
</config>
```

> **Create a file: CustomerRegister.php**
>
> **File: app/code/[Vendor]/[modulename]/Observer/CustomerRegister.php**

```
    <?php
namespace [Vendor]\[modulename]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerRegister implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    private $responseFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;

    public function __construct(
        ......
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        ......
    ) {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
        $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

> **Create a file: CustomerLogin.php**
>
> **File: app/code/[Vendor]/[modulename]/Observer/CustomerLogin.php**

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[modulename]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    private $responseFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;

    public function __construct(
        ......
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        ......
    ) {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
        $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();

        return $this;
    }
}
```